# Auto post on database from RSS by PHP

Tags: php, sql, rss

I have this

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?        
   require_once 'rss_fetch.inc';
   $url = 'http://egyptian-planet.com/rss.php';
   $rss = fetch_rss($url);

   echo "Site: ", $rss->channel['title'], "<br>";

   foreach ($rss->items as $item ) {
        $title = $item[title];
        $url   = $item[link];
        $pub   = $item[pubdate];
        $desc  = $item[description]; 


   $select_url = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM rssnews where url = '$url'");
   $num_url = $select_url->num_rows;

   if($num_url){
       echo "";
   }else{
       $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO rssnews (id, title, url, date, desc1)
                 VALUE('', '$title', '$url', '$pub', '$desc')");
   }
}   
?>
```

But this code does not add news to database automatic 
I must refresh page.

How can I make this code add news to database automatic?

Answer (score 2):

It only works when you refresh the page because that is the only way the code is told to execute. If you want this to run automatically you need to run a [cron job](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html).